# Event listener on keydown inside a loop fires once, but does not fire again unless the loop is restarted. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The following jQuery is inside a for-loop:

```
$(document).one('keydown',function(e) {
    if( e.which === 90 && leftPosition + 50 <= maxHeight) {
        var newLeftPosition = (leftPosition + 1) + 'px';
        $("#leftPaddle").css({top:newLeftPosition});         
    }
});
```

For each iteration it should fire once if the z key is pressed.  It fires the first time, but does not fire again unless you restart the loop after the loop has finished.  I originally had the following, and it too only fired once:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which === 90 && leftPosition + 50 <= maxHeight) {
        var newLeftPosition = (leftPosition + 1) + 'px';
        $("#leftPaddle").css({top:newLeftPosition});         
    }   
});
```

The drawback to the second snippet, besides the fact that it too only fired once, is that it stopped the loop until the key was no longer pressed.

The variable leftPosition is set inside the for-loop and should update each iteration.  It is declared and initialized as follows:

```
var leftPosition = $("#leftPaddle").position().top;
```

The CSS for #leftPaddle is as follows:

```
#leftPaddle {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:8px;
  height:48px;
  background-color:#BADA55;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/6J5P7/), to see it in action.

-Bonus cool points.  If I create an infinite loop, the jsFiddle fails to load and freezes the browser.  Is that a fiddle issue?

Comment: And an infinite loop wouldn't freeze the browser anyway? Ah browsers these days with script kill on timeouts... ;)

Comment: If I just do $(document).keydown(function(){ console.log("!"); }); it works fine, even when I hold a key.

You shouldn't have to do a for loop.

The reason you're probably having this problem is because the event listener was attached, but the event was not re-fired until you let up and pressed the z key again.

Comment: The for-loop is to bounce a ball around.  In the loop, while the ball is bouncing, I want to move a div if the z key is pressed.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Then use a bool.

Comment: @ShengSlogar even if I let up on the key and press again, it still doesn't fire.  A boolean?  Where and how?

Comment: @BotskoNet Shouldn't it still load and run though?

Comment: @MatthewJohnson Come to think of it, you wouldn't be able to do a bool, because you are running a for loop, which would freeze all other code (JavaScript is single-threaded). Maybe you should use setInterval - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval.

Comment: That got it, @ShengSlogar.  Upvoted comment, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShengSlogar got it.  Instead of wrapping the listener in a for-loop, I used setInterval, as follows:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(document).one('keydown',function(e) {
      if( e.which === 90 && leftPosition + 50 <= maxHeight) {
          var newLeftPosition = (leftPosition + 1) + 'px';
          $("#leftPaddle").css({top:newLeftPosition});         
      }
    });
}, 1);
```

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help! (I should've made a code snippet instead of making you do all the hard work though...)

Comment: I don't mind the work, I just needed the direction.  If you want to post an answer I can accept/upvote it.  Thanks again!

Comment: Nope. You got the answer. No reason for me to post an answer just to get upvoted. :)

Comment: don't forget to use `clearInterval` when the game ends or gets paused

Comment: Thanks for that, because I'm sure I would have.  +1!  After I get my kids to bed I'm going to finish the controls, then I'll worry about the ball hitting the paddles or wall, and win condition.  Keep an eye out, more questions to come, I'm sure!